# Use Tags to initiate Search

Tags: php, search, tags

first of all im new to Wordpress and PHP and i apologize if this is a basic question.
I have a Wordpress installation and every post is marked with Tags and these Tags contain a link with:

```
href=domain.com/index.php/tag/TAGNAME
```

but i want the Link to be:

```
href=domain.com/index.php/search/TAGNAME
```

As far as i understand it i need to change the `get_tag_link()` but all is does is use the `get_term_link()` and then im totaly lost. Is there somewere a function which says `If(tag){ return "/tag/"}` which i can modify?
The Theme i use uses this function for "breadcrumbs" http://dimox.net/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/ but i dont know if this i relevant in any form.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your **Tag base** in permalinks setting on your website.

[image]

PS : By default /search/ is a slug for a search result page.  To avoid conflict with search result page you may also need to rewrite search url. 
check this page to rewrite search url

https://bavotasan.com/2011/rewrite-search-result-url-for-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks, but i actually wanted to provoke this conflict since i didn't know how to start a search for post based on Tags. I tried it and it automatically changes my search url.

Comment: I tried this on my localsite and its worked. I change my search url with /browse/ and didnt find any conflict

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround for now. I eddited the category_template.php with the str_replace function. The problem turned out to be that the Tag Cloud used diffenten functions than the regular Tags. I just added this:

```
foreach ( $tags_data as $key => $tag_data ) {

$class = $tag_data['class'] . ' tag-link-position-' . ( $key + 1 );
 $a[] = "<a href='" . str_replace("/index.php/tag/","/index.php/search/",esc_url( $tag_data['url'] )) .(...)
}
```

to wp_generate_tag_cloud() and this:

```
$the_tags = str_replace("/index.php/tag/","/index.php/search/",$the_tags);
```

to the_tags(). As stated bevor I'm new to this and I dont think thats the way it should be but it works for now. I used it with the BeTube Theme if anyone wants to use this as well.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the URLs in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ http://example.com/search/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Put this above the default WP .htaccess contents and replace example.com with your actual domain.

Comment: Thanks, but I think i dont have a .htaccess, i run this Wordpress on an nginx Server

Comment: Depends on the host, some enable .htaccess even on Nginx, but it will be faster if you use Nginx's own redirect methods: https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/